# how to handle links path in a dynamic site using mod_rewrite for clean url

Tags: php, jquery, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

say i have a function:

```
function ajax()
{   $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
 url:'index.php',
 data:{t:t},
 success:function(data)
 {  if(data)
 { 
  alert(data);
  }


 }
```

i am using this function all  over my  pages,the problem is  when i am in  homepage 
 i.e :www/mysite.com  it is  fine but when i am  in a  page like this 
  www/mysite.com/modrewrite where modrewrite is not a  folder but instead a  mod_rewrite thing  the ajax function returns 404  error,but when i  modify it to ../index.php then it does not work in homepage.what should be done to make it work in all the pages!

Comment: Show your `.htaccess` content?

Comment: RewriteEngine On  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9.]+)$ page.php?uri=$1

Comment: another problem i am having is when it is con  it shows  mysite/con  but if i  have con.1  it  shows 404  error

Comment: just updated the  code.please see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see how it works for your ajax or use the full path.

```
function ajax(){   
   $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'/index.php',
      data:{t:t},
      success:function(data){  
         if(data){
           alert(data);
          }
      }
    });
}
```

Then in your `.htaccess` use this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9.]+)$ page.php?uri=$1
```